# Display results according to a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to display a table according to a variable but I am getting errors on the view.
Here is the database function that gets the results, I'm passing in the value `$series`.

```
function getReviews($series) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT review FROM reviews
              where series = :series';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':series', $series);
    $statement->execute();
    $reviews = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();    
    return $reviews;
}
```

And here is the view

```
<div id="reviews" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Reviews</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Review</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($reviews as $review) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $reviews['review']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am getting some sort of result as there are 3 reviews under `$series = 1`, but they aren't displaying

> Notice: Undefined index: review in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBCA5LP\view\main.php on line 52
>
> Notice: Undefined index: review in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBCA5LP\view\main.php on line 52
>
> Notice: Undefined index: review in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBCA5LP\view\main.php on line 52

Comment: "but I am getting errors on the view" - what errors? could you include them in your post"

Comment: I think you want to use `$review` inside the foreach, not `$reviews`.

Comment: Why don't you pass the $series variable straight into the query string instead of binding it? `$query = 'SELECT review FROM reviews
     where series = '.$series;`

Comment: PHP is not python - no colon after foreach. Use $review as the output variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are echoing the wrong thing - $review not $reviews

```
<?php foreach ($reviews as $review) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $review['review']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, just a little mistake that sometimes you don't spot. Sorry for wasting time !