# codeigniter pass value without method

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my application How pass the value pf news view to editNews view without useing get or post methods anyway to that
my code is

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url();?>admin/editNews?newsid=<?php echo $news_row->id;?>" method="post">
                    <button class="btn-default btn" name="edit" type="submit">&nbsp&nbsp Edit &nbsp&nbsp </button>
                    <button class="btn-default btn" name="delete" type="submit" >Delete</button>
                  </form>
```

and editNews.php is

```
      <div class="col_1">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post"
       action="<?php echo base_url() ."admin/updateNews"?>">
       <fieldset>
         <legend>News ID #: <?php echo $editableNews->id; ?></legend>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >ID</label>
           <div class="col-md-1">
             <input id="news_id_in" readonly name="ed_news_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $editableNews->id; ?>" class="form-control input-md">
           </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display results according to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944548/display-results-according-to-a-variable)

Comment: Do the tutorial in the codeigniter manual and your questions will be answered quickly https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I main between two views

Comment: using query string you can send data on view to another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send data on View to another View using "uri segment"

**in your sender view**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>admin/editNews?newsid=<?php echo $news_row->id;?>">click</a>
```

and get this data using uri segment in editNews view

```
$this->uri->segment();
```